# How many Chebyshev nodes are necessary to approximate the function $\sin(xπ)$

Tags: trigonometry, numerical-methods

I am trying to understand Chebyshev Interpolation, and having trouble understanding this problem.

How many Chebyshev nodes are necessary to approximate the function $\sin(x\pi)$ to an error of at most $10^{-10}$ within $[-1, 1]$?

I think we can define a $y = x\pi$ so that we can reduce the problem to $\sin(y)$ within $[-\pi, \pi]$. But how can I continue from here, how do I determine how many Chebyshev nodes are needed?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

"Necessary" is a tough question.  "Sufficient" is easier to answer.

Recall the interpolation error for an $n$-times continuously differentiable $f$ on $[-1,1]$ using Chebyshev nodes $x_k=\cos((2k-1)\pi/(2n))$, $k=1,\dots,n$, is
$$
\leq\frac{1}{2^{n-1}n!}\max_{\xi\in[-1,1]}\lvert f^{(n)}(\xi)\rvert.
$$
With $f(x)=\sin(\pi x)$, we have $\max_{\xi\in[-1,1]}\lvert f^{(n)}(\xi)\rvert=\pi^n$ and so for sufficiency we just need to guarantee
$$
\frac{\pi^n}{2^{n-1}n!}\leq 10^{-10}.
$$
so $n\geq 17$ is sufficient.

If you really want the necessary number of nodes, then you go back and test the interpolation for $n=16,15,\dots$ to find out where it fails.  It is going to be an ugly computation.